# Не подключается к ftp на deban

Tags: debian, vsftpd

Установил vsftpd на debian. В файле настроек стоит возможность анонимного доступа. Но он не подключается. Даже когда на самом сервере пишу ftp localhost (нашел в нете что так можно), то мне пишет "Connection refused"
netstat -nlpt показывает [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Почему то нету 21 порта. Хотя vsftpd я запустил

Comment: Пробовали `service vsftpd restart`? У Вас просто не запущен сервис FTP.

Comment: @RostislavDugin все равно нет